# UIImage - How can I modify a portion of the image and replace the original image with the modified version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm applying a mask recursively (using a timer) to an image in a UIImageView, and I want to apply the mask in a certain region depending on where the user touches the screen.

To define that region, the user touches the screen and the touch current location is read. This location defines the center of the region I want to modify.

So far I can only apply the mask to the whole image using `CGImageCreateWithMask`. The code I use to apply the mask is:

```
- (UIImage *)maskImageWithCurrentContext:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage{
    UIImage *maskedImage;

    float width = image.size.width;
    float height = image.size.height;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef),
                                    NULL,
                                    false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(image.CGImage, mask);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, masked);

    maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGImageRelease(masked);

    return maskedImage;
}
```

The way I call the method is `self.imageViewGelo.image = [self maskImageWithCurrentContext:self.imageViewGelo.image withMask:self.imageMask];` (inside the timer that is activated when the view is touched) and the resulting image is then applied to the view which I want to modify.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to get a region of the whole image, apply the mask to it, and then apply the new region in the original image, in order to show the modifications. For example, if I have an image with dimensions 1024x768, and the user touches the point with coordinates (300, 200), I want to select a region with dimensions 50x50, apply the mask, then place the resulting image in that same region.

The mask I'm using is almost all black, and have some regions with slightly more "light" (like really dark shades of gray), in order to give an effect of slow ice melting.

I've already read the documentation and searched for hours about any similar questions, but with no luck.

The performance of the code above running on an iPad 4, with the timer set to fire every 0.1 seconds (only a test value) is pretty good, without any memory issues and relatively low processor usage.

Thanks a lot in advance if someone can help me with this question.

Comment: Can you ask a specific question? You haven't even included a question mark in your post.

Comment: Sorry mate! I already changed the title. You're right.

Comment: UIImages are immutable.  So send the image to the method and save it in the same UIImage coming out.  image - [self changeImage: image]; - Edit Sorry that's what you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my code working as I intended.

First I crop a portion of the image in the location touched by the user, using code based on the one provided by Matt in the [following post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618835/core-graphics-how-to-crop-non-transparent-pixels-out-of-a-uiimage?rq=1) Thank you Matt. :)

My code to crop the image is:

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)original{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(kSizeMaskImageWidth, kSizeMaskImageHeight), NO, original.scale);

    [original drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-((int)touchLocation.x - kSizeMaskImageWidth / 2), -((int)touchLocation.y - kSizeMaskImageHeight / 2))];
    UIImage *cropped = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return cropped;
}
```

Next, I draw a transparent rectangle in the exact same location, with exactly the same dimensions, where I apply the cropped image that I get in the previous code. To achieve all this, I use the following code:

```
- (UIImage *)maskImageWithCurrentContext:(UIImage *)originalImage withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage inCroppedImage:(UIImage *)croppedImage{
    float width = originalImage.size.width;
    float height = originalImage.size.height;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, originalImage.scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef),
                                    NULL,
                                    false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(croppedImage.CGImage, mask);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, originalImage.CGImage);
    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(((int)touchLocation.x - kSizeMaskImageWidth / 2), height - ((int)touchLocation.y + kSizeMaskImageHeight / 2), kSizeMaskImageWidth, kSizeMaskImageHeight));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(((int)touchLocation.x - kSizeMaskImageWidth / 2), height - ((int)touchLocation.y + kSizeMaskImageHeight / 2), kSizeMaskImageWidth, kSizeMaskImageHeight), masked);

    UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGImageRelease(masked);

    return maskedImage;
}
```

With this code, the original image is drawn, then the transparent rectangle is drawn on top of the original image, and finally the cropped image is drawn inside the transparent rectangle.

I had some issues with the touches location in a retina iPad, as the touches are detected in points. When I was trying to draw the image, sometimes the location was x,5, so I had to cast it to an int, in order to get rid of the decimal places.

Now I achieved an effect of melting ice, using a timer to apply the mask recursively, and applying it where the user touches the screen. :)

As a last note, as the touches are detected faster than the timer interval I am using, I disable the touches in the view before drawing, and enable them again when the drawing is done.